# svnserve and SASL problem

Tags: svn, ubuntu, svnserve

I have configured svn server in my system and have made following configuration for authenticating users with SASL MD5. I have made following changes in the svnserve.conf

```
 [general]
 anon-access = none
 auth-access = write
 password-db = passwd
 authz-db = authz
 realm = my_first_repository
 [SASL]
 use-sasl = true 
 min-encryption = 0
 max-encryption = 256 


 /usr/local/lib/sasl2/subversion.conf
 pwcheck_method: auxprop 
 auxprop_plugin: sasldb 
 sasldb_path: /etc/my_sasldb
 mech_list: DIGEST-MD5
```

i am adding the user by the following command

```
 saslpasswd2 -c -f /etc/my_sasldb -u my_first_repository username
```

it asks for the  password and it checks for the correctness of password. But once i enter the username and password using the following command

```
 svn list svn://localhost/path/to/repository/ --username
```

it shows following warning

```
svn: Authentication error from server: SASL(-13): user not found: no secret in database
```

what can be the reason for it? Any suggestion will be highly appreciated.

moreover,

i am getting following warning while starting the svn server. i am configuring server in ubuntu 10.04. And the version of svn is 1.6.6.

```
 svnserve: /usr/local/lib/libsasl2.so.2: no version information available (required by svnserve)
 svnserve: /usr/local/lib/libsasl2.so.2: no version information available (required by /usr/lib/libsvn_ra_svn-1.so.1)
 svnserve: /usr/local/lib/libsasl2.so.2: no version information available (required by /usr/lib/libldap_r-2.4.so.2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same SASL error after I had added the users into SASL until I rebooted.