# PHP exec throwing unexpected results

Tags: php, lampp, bitnami

I am trying to automate my deployment using phing. I get the below error when I use svnlastrevision task

> Execution of target "builddiff" failed for the following reason: /home/ramjee/Work/Projects/it/dev-stack/build.xml:88:1: Failed to parse the output of 'svn info --xml'.

On debugging the issue further I zeroed it on to the following:

The following is a small program to recreate the issue:

```
$cmd = "/usr/bin/svn info --non-interactive '/home/ramjee/Work/Projects/trunk/src' '--xml'";
exec("$cmd 2>&1",$out,$ret_var);

print_r($out);
```

When I execute the above

i. With PHP (5.2.17) that is shipped with bitnami lampstack.1.2-5. I get the following result (not expected):

```
Array
(
    [0] => /usr/bin/svn: /home/ramjee/Work/lampstack-1.2-5/common/lib/libsasl2.so.2: no version information available (required by /usr/lib/libldap_r-2.4.so.2)
    [1] => /usr/bin/svn: /home/ramjee/Work/lampstack-1.2-5/common/lib/libsasl2.so.2: no version information available (required by /usr/lib/libsvn_ra_svn-1.so.1)
    [2] => <?xml version="1.0"?>
    [3] => <info>
    [4] => <entry
    [5] =>    kind="dir"
    [6] =>    path="/home/ramjee/Work/Projects/trunk/src"
    [7] =>    revision="818">
    [8] => <url>svn://abc.abc.abc.abc/data/repositories/src</url>
    [9] => <repository>
    [10] => <root>svn://abc.abc.abc.abc/data/repositories/</root>
    [11] => <uuid>f74a063e-5e8e-11e0-b400-13ff509e0209</uuid>
    [12] => </repository>
    [13] => <wc-info>
    [14] => <schedule>normal</schedule>
    [15] => <depth>infinity</depth>
    [16] => </wc-info>
    [17] => <commit
    [18] =>    revision="802">
    [19] => <author>shweta</author>
    [20] => <date>2012-01-03T12:07:46.427638Z</date>
    [21] => </commit>
    [22] => </entry>
    [23] => </info>
)
```

ii. With PHP (5.3.17) which was part of a lampp setup. I get the following result (expected):

```
Array
(
    [0] => <?xml version="1.0"?>
    [1] => <info>
    [2] => <entry
    [3] =>    kind="dir"
    [4] =>    path="/home/ramjee/Work/Projects/trunk/src"
    [5] =>    revision="818">
    [6] => <url>svn://abc.abc.abc.abc/data/repositories/src</url>
    [7] => <repository>
    [8] => <root>svn://abc.abc.abc.abc/data/repositories/</root>
    [9] => <uuid>f74a063e-5e8e-11e0-b400-13ff509e0209</uuid>
    [10] => </repository>
    [11] => <wc-info>
    [12] => <schedule>normal</schedule>
    [13] => <depth>infinity</depth>
    [14] => </wc-info>
    [15] => <commit
    [16] =>    revision="802">
    [17] => <author>shweta</author>
    [18] => <date>2012-01-03T12:07:46.427638Z</date>
    [19] => </commit>
    [20] => </entry>
    [21] => </info>
)
```

In the first line we have two unwanted lines which cause the phing task to throw error.

I don't know how to fix this? Any help on this will be very valuable.

Comment: Have a look at http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=5883384&postcount=3 and see if that fixes your issue.

Comment: I tried that, and it doesn't help. I guess in this case, the libraries are picked from lamp path and not the shared library path. (though not sure)

Comment: A hacky workaround would be to remove the `2>&1` part of the exec, as the XML seems valid otherwise. As far as the error is concerned, I only found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3535110/svnserve-and-sasl-problem). Also, [a bit more info](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/137773/what-does-the-no-version-information-available-error-from-linux-dynamic-linker) on shared objects.

Comment: Wonderful the hack worked, any idea what is the impact of this change. I have to make this change in a third party library so little concerned about the impact (also if you can put it as an answer will select it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a great solution, as it simply masks the problem (and potentially other problems), but you can remove the `2>&1` part from the exec:

```
exec($cmd, $out, $ret_var);
```

`2>&1` is used in bash to redirect STDERR (where the first 2 lines are being sent) to STDOUT (where the XML is sent) — see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/818255/in-the-bash-shell-what-is-21) for more information.

The impact of this is that you're masking the error, and any other errors that you may encounter in the future from that command. Here's a longer solution that still involves you patching the library, but at least feels like less of a hack:

```
$cmd = "/usr/bin/svn info --non-interactive '/home/ramjee/Work/Projects/trunk/src' '--xml'";

$descriptors = array(
    1 => array('pipe', 'w'), // stdout
    2 => array('pipe', 'w')  // stderr
);

$process = proc_open($cmd, $descriptors, $pipes);

$out = $err = '';
while ($data = fgets($pipes[1])) { $out .= $data; } // contains your XML
while ($data = fgets($pipes[2])) { $err .= $data; } // contains any errors (which you can log)
```

Comment: thanks cbuckley, since this is an internal application for me (used to automate my build), I am going on with first solution. But thanks for the detailed solution.